# Do cards acquired with The Amazing Spider-Man count as extra draws?

Tags: legendary-marvel

The card *The Amazing Spider-Man* includes the following effect:

> Reveal the top three cards of your deck. Put any that cost 2 or less into your hand. Put the rest back in any order.

Meanwhile, the card *Berserker Rage* (for Wolverine) includes this effect:

> You get +1 attack for each extra card you've drawn this turn.

Does putting a card in your hand with *The Amazing Spider-Man* count as drawing an extra card for the purposes of *Berserker Rage* and similar effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, putting cards in your hand is distinctly different to drawing cards. Wolverine's Berserker Rage only counts for cards gained through an ability that says to *"draw a card"*, or *"draw that card"*, or *"draw X cards"* etc.

Devin Low (designer of the game) clarified this point [in this question on boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/14664653#14664653).

Comment: So if it uses the word "draw" it's an extra draw, and if it doesn't then it isn't? I wasn't sure, since some keywords (Phasing from Civil War, for example) explicitly say that the cards they put in your hand do not count as extra draws, but I didn't see anything like that for Spider-Man's (and Symbiote Spider-Man's) ability.

Comment: Yeah, it was never specified back when Paint the Town Red came out. I think the designers just assumed that the different wording was enough, but now knowing better they are clarifying it where it is needed. I know I played it incorrectly for quite a while until I found that answer on BGG.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the difference by the key words "reveal" vs. "draw". Draw means put it into your hand. Reveal just means to look at it and (potentially) put it back where you found it.